# 'git branch' simply shows nothing at all

Tags: git

When I do 'git branch', nothing happens; I can't see the branches I have been working on recently. I'm not sure what I did to screw it up, but I'm pretty much certain I didn't mess around with any git files between now and when it used to work.

Comment: Can you show the excact command you are trying to excecute?

Comment: And include the directory from where you executed that command.

Comment: what does `git status` say?

Comment: can you try checking out the remote branches `git remote show origin       ` Shows all the branches at remote origin

Comment: @Roberto git status works fine; shows the usual correct info about my branch, changed files etc

Comment: @Koenman simply 'git branch' returns nothing, not even a newline - 
 I'm using this command in a folder in the local repo (in this folder, other commands like commit, push, etc work fine)

Comment: @SrikanthJosyula your command worked, but 'git branch' afterwards still doesn't do anything

Comment: @EdwardK may be your fork branch is not having any branches, u need to bind your local branch with upstream branch `git checkout -b <Branch Name> upstream/<Upstream Branch Name>` try using this command

Comment: @SrikanthJosyula This is not the issue; I am able to checkout, commit, and push to branches that exist, I just cannot see anything from git diff.

Answer (score 2):

Did you just recently re-clone this repository?

`git branch` shows *local* branches.

`git branch -r` shows *remote* branches.

`git branch -a` shows *all* branches.

Give those a shot.

Comment: This is a long running local instance of the repository; git branch only stopped working recently. Using those flags didn't change the result, thanks though

Answer (score -2):

It is possible that you are not currently in a git repository. The `git branch -a` command only shows branches within a repository. If you are not in a repository, then it will show nothing.

Or you have not committed yet.

Comment: Before answering next time, could you try what you're suggesting?